# Delete calendar entries

Tags: android, calendar

I wrote simple code for deleting all entries from android calendar,but it didn't delete nothing.

Source code:

```
public void DeleteEvent(View view){

            int iNumRowsDeleted = 0;
            Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
            Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(eventsUri, null, null, null, null);

            while (cur.moveToNext()){

                long id = cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                Log.d(TAG, "ID: " + id);
                Uri eventUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(eventsUri, id);
                iNumRowsDeleted = getContentResolver().delete(eventUri, null, null);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Man @Husky .. its working for me :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use this for delete:

```
private void deleteEvent(ContentResolver resolver, Uri eventsUri, int calendarId) {
    Cursor cursor;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 7) { //up-to Android 2.1 
        cursor = resolver.query(eventsUri, new String[]{ "_id" }, "Calendars._id=" + calendarId, null, null);
    } else { //8 is Android 2.2 (Froyo) (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html)
        cursor = resolver.query(eventsUri, new String[]{ "_id" }, "calendar_id=" + calendarId, null, null);
    }
    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        long eventId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        resolver.delete(ContentUris.withAppendedId(eventsUri, eventId), null, null);
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

I call it with something like this:

```
Uri eventsUri;
int osVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (osVersion <= 7) { //up-to Android 2.1 
    eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
} else { //8 is Android 2.2 (Froyo) (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html)
    eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
}
ContentResolver resolver = this.getContentResolver();
deleteEvent(resolver, eventsUri, calendarId);
```

Comment: Android can have (and usually has) multiple calendars. CalendarId is integer that represents calendar that you wish to use.

Comment: but here it will delete all the event that are present in the calendar..but if i want to delete only that event that are put by my app not the event that are already there in my calendar than how that can be done...

Comment: @AndroidDev did you get the solution. please help me, I am stuck with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

use this code its right

```
        public void DeleteEvent(int your_event_id){

        int iNumRowsDeleted = 0;
        Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(eventsUri, null, null, null, null);

        while (cur.moveToNext()){

             Uri eventUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(eventsUri, your_event_id);
            iNumRowsDeleted = getContentResolver().delete(eventUri, null, null);
        }
    }
```