# Android,Delete contact

Tags: android

How can I delete all the contacts?

Comment: What has not working for you? Post some code what you have tried so far!

Answer (score 0):

Previously asked and answered (I assume you've looked at it since your code is very similar): [Delete calendar entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806174/delete-calendar-entries)

Do you have the necessary permissions to access that provider (you need `READ_CALENDAR` and `WRITE_CALENDAR`)?

Comment: Ah. For that take a look at http://jimblackler.net/blog/?p=151, which talks about fetching the calendars on a device. I expect you will need to do the same version-check and use a different calendar URL as that is old.