# How to delete specific event in calendar

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

What I want to do is to delete only the content that is saved by me in the calendar instead of all the content which is already present in the calendar. For that, I use the following code. But it will delete all the content of the calendar. So can anyone tell me how that can be prevented?

```
Uri CALENDAR_URI = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
cr.delete(CALENDAR_URI, null, null); // Delete all



ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("calendar_id", 1);
values.put("title", this.title);
values.put("allDay", this.allDay);
values.put("dtstart", this.dtstart.toMillis(false));
values.put("dtend", this.dtend.toMillis(false));
values.put("description", this.description);
values.put("eventLocation", this.eventLocation);
values.put("visibility", this.visibility);
values.put("hasAlarm", this.hasAlarm);

cr.insert(CALENDAR_URI, values);
```

So what I want is to delete only that entry that is put by me.

**Deleting the event**

```
Uri EVENTS_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/" + "events");
            
ContentResolver cr = c.getContentResolver();
deleteEvent(cr, EVENTS_URI, 1);

private void deleteEvent(ContentResolver resolver, Uri eventsUri, int calendarId) {
        Cursor cursor;     
        cursor = resolver.query(eventsUri, new String[]{ "_id" },     "calendar_id=" + calendarId, null, null);
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            long eventId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            resolver.delete(ContentUris.withAppendedId(eventsUri, eventId), null, null);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
```

Comment: This'll work only if there's the default Calendar application installed on the phone.

Comment: Use the Google Calendar GData API to manipulate a user's Google Calendar, please.

Comment: @Andr Hi I am facing same issue, how did you solved the issue...Any suggestions will be very help full for us ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading the data from the Calendar just try this out..

Adding a Single-Occurrence Event to a Calendar

To add an entry to a specific calendar, we need to configure a calendar entry to insert using the ContentValues as follows:

```
ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
```

Each event needs to be tied to a specific Calendar, so the first thing you're going to want to set is the identifier of the Calendar to insert this event into:

```
event.put("calendar_id", calId);
```

We then set some of the basic information about the event, including String fields such as the event title, description and location.

```
event.put("title", "Event Title");
event.put("description", "Event Desc");
event.put("eventLocation", "Event Location");
```

There are a number of different options for configuring the time and date of an event.

We can set the event start and end information as follows:

```
long startTime = START_TIME_MS;
long endTime = END_TIME_MS;
event.put("dtstart", startTime);
event.put("dtend", endTime);
```

If we are adding a birthday or holiday, we would set the entry to be an all day event:

```
event.put("allDay", 1);   // 0 for false, 1 for true
```

This information is sufficient for most entries. However, there are a number of other useful calendar entry attributes.

For example, you can set the event status to tentative (0), confirmed (1) or canceled (2):

```
event.put("eventStatus", 1);
```

You can control who can see this event by setting its visibility to default (0), confidential (1), private (2), or public (3):

```
event.put("visibility", 0);
```

You can control whether an event consumes time (can have schedule conflicts) on the calendar by setting its transparency to opaque (0) or transparent (1).

```
event.put("transparency", 0);
```

You can control whether an event triggers a reminder alarm as follows:

event.put("hasAlarm", 1); // 0 for false, 1 for true

Once the calendar event is configured correctly, we're ready to use the `ContentResolver` to insert the new calendar entry into the appropriate Uri for calendar events:

```
 Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
  Uri url = getContentResolver().insert(eventsUri, event);
```

The call to the insert() method contacts the Calendar content provider and attempts to insert the entry into the appropriate user Calendar. If you navigate to the Calendar application and launch it, you should see your calendar entry in the appropriate Calendar. Since the Calendar syncs, you will also see the Calendar entry online, if you're using the Google Calendar on the web.

**Delete the event**

```
 private int DeleteCalendarEntry(int entryID) {
        int iNumRowsDeleted = 0;

        Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase()+"events");
        Uri eventUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(eventsUri, entryID);
        iNumRowsDeleted = getContentResolver().delete(eventUri, null, null);

        Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Deleted " + iNumRowsDeleted + " calendar entry.");

        return iNumRowsDeleted;
    }
```

Also go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806174/delete-calendar-entries) for deleting

Comment: but what about the delete option..actually insertion is done but now when i tried to delete content that are put by my app..it will delete the content but also all the content that are already there in calendar

Comment: yeh i have tried your code again the same thing happen it delete all the content of the calendar..which means it delete the content that are put by my app and also the content that are put by other..

Comment: i send u my updated code for deleting you please check it..why does happen..i need only those thing deleted that are set by my app in device calendar

Comment: Sorry anshuman :(, i just know these things in the calender events. I dint used more than this. I think u can make use of this and build ur code.