# Deleting default events in android calendar

Tags: android, events, calendar

I wanted to delete the default events which have been added / exist in the Android device calendar. I followed the following to delete :

[How to delete specific event in calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924438/how-to-delete-specific-event-in-calendar)

But it deletes only the user added events, not the default ones. How to achieve it? Is it the problem with Google Server sync up?

If it is not possible to delete, is there any way that I can distinguish between user added events and the default ones?

Comment: I'm not using the standard calender, but what are default events? If they are vital notification for the user, I'm pretty sure, google will not give you api access to delete them.