# Deleting a google calendar event in android

Tags: android, android-studio, google-calendar-api

I used google calendar api and it is working nice, showing events, date and time.
I want to know how to delete a event from google calendar.

```
     private class MakeRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {
        private com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar mService = null;
        private Exception mLastError = null;

        public MakeRequestTask(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
            HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
            mService = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
                    transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                    .setApplicationName("Google Calendar API Android Quickstart")
                    .build();
        }


        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                return getDataFromApi();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                mLastError = e;
                cancel(true);
                return null;
            }
        }

        private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
            // List the next 10 events from the primary calendar.
            DateTime now = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
            List<String> eventStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
            Events events = mService.events().list("primary")
                    .setMaxResults(10)
                    .setTimeMin(now)
                    .setOrderBy("startTime")
                    .setSingleEvents(true)
                    .execute();
            List<Event> items = events.getItems();

            for (Event event : items) {

               String Location = event.getLocation(); // Getting location

//                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Location " + Location, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                DateTime start = event.getStart().getDateTime();
                if (start == null) {
                    // All-day events don't have start times, so just use
                    // All-day events don't have start times, so just use
                    // the start date.
                    start = event.getStart().getDate();
                }
                eventStrings.add(
                        String.format("%s (%s)", event.getSummary(), start));
            }
            return eventStrings;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mOutputText.setText("");
            mProgress.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> output) {
            mProgress.hide();
            if (output == null || output.size() == 0) {
                mOutputText.setText("No results returned.");
            } else {
                output.add(0, "Data retrieved using the Google Calendar API:");
                mOutputText.setText(TextUtils.join("\n", output));
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            mProgress.hide();
            if (mLastError != null) {
                if (mLastError instanceof GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) {
                    showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
                            ((GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) mLastError)
                                    .getConnectionStatusCode());
                } else if (mLastError instanceof UserRecoverableAuthIOException) {
                    startActivityForResult(
                            ((UserRecoverableAuthIOException) mLastError).getIntent(),
                            MainActivity.REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
                } else {
                    mOutputText.setText("The following error occurred:\n"
                            + mLastError.getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                mOutputText.setText("Request cancelled.");
            }
        }
```

This is the code i have used for getting event from google calendar. Is there any way i can delete the event from calendar.
Any example will be appreciated. 
Note : (Google calendar is used here so need to delete google calendar event not the pre-installed calendar)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete specific event in calendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924438/how-to-delete-specific-event-in-calendar)

Comment: How it is duplicate ? I am asking about the google calendar not the pre installed mobile calendar

Comment: Why you don't work with google calendar throw [Calendar Provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll just need to call the [`delete(calendarId, eventId)`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/calendar/Calendar.Events.html#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method and `AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute()` after it.